# SKMaps blank screen after random periods

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, skmaps

I'm developing an application using the SKMaps framework and I'm having a couple of consistent issues.

```
mapView2.settings.followUserPosition = YES;
mapView2.settings.headingMode = SKHeadingModeRoute;
mapView2.settings.displayMode = SKMapDisplayMode3D;
```

a\ Whilst routing, the navigation works correctly. But when not routing, and the map is in `SKMapDisplayMode3D` and set to `followUserPosition = YES;`, after random periods of time, the maps disappear & the compass turns blank. The user has not touched anything. 
The map is simply there to display the current user position as they're driving, and everything goes blank. If they click a button which begins routing, the maps appear back, but they shouldn't have to route and end route just to get the maps back. Any idea's why and what I can add to my app to fix this issue?

b\ `mapView2.settings.headingMode` works for a few minutes and then the compass faces the complete wrong way. My app works in landscape mode, when launching the app the compass faces the correct location, and after a few moments, starts to drift more and more in the wrong direction. Unless the user is routing, the compass points some random other direction. Is there a setting which keeps the compass pointing in the direction of travel like it does when routing?
I have tried the following:

```
SKHeadingModeRoute
SKHeadingModeRotatingMap
SKHeadingModeRotatingHeading
```

Thanks

Comment: What sdk version you are using?

Comment: @Adrian.B I'm not sure where to check unfortunately, but I'm pretty confident it was the latest version. 3.x.x. I only downloaded the framework 5-6 months ago.